# Evil twin in UCM ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have an issue with an "Evil twin" in UCM ClearCase.
I do know what an evil twin is and we have a trigger in place that prevents me from creating one.
The thing is I obviously had a file checked in to ClearCase already (at the same location I would like to add it now again) but removed it. For the removal I used the Windows ClearCase Explorer version 7.0.1.6.
I don't know which command the GUI uses but as rmelem is bad I would guess that Rational did not setup the GUI to issue this command...

My question: How do I get the file into ClearCase again?
The trigger tells me that the evil twin would be created with version /main/INT-STREAM/DEV-STREAM/2 of the directory. So I tried to get a view with version 2 of the directory (so I could at least have a look at the version where the evil twin would occur) but using the following config spec does not display the folder:

```
element PathToFolder/folder/... .../DEV-STREAM/2
element PathToFolder .../INT-STREAM/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST>
```

I also tried

```
element PathToFolder/folder .../DEV-STREAM/2
element PathToFolder/folder/... .../DEV-STREAM/LATEST
element PathToFolder .../INT-STREAM/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

but that does not display the folder either.

Thanks in advance for any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot select just a folder with a specific selection rule: you need to make sure all the parent folders are at the right version (potentially in the `DEV-STREAM` branch as well).

But in your case, I would rather try and access that old file though the **[extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)** in order to directly access the content of that older version of that folder.

```
cd PathToFolder/folder@@/main/INT-STREAM/x/DEV-STREAM/2
```

(you might have to adapt that extended path, as I have replaced intermediate version numbers by 'x': do a property on the current version of that folder to see the exact extended path).

---

You can, after comparing the content of that folder, try manual resolutions of an evil twin, as described in :

- "[When clearcase “evil twins” will be created and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13283627/6309)"
- [Using a substractive merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637405/6309)
- "[Restoring an element that has been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426339/6309)"

Comment: Note to @user2606240: I mentioned (to you) this selection rule for parent folder before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17784425/6309 (7 months ago).

Comment: Hi, yes you have mentioned that rule before and I thought I had taken care of that with the rule for PathToFolder. Anyway I could cd into the parent folder (PathToFolder) and found out that not the file but rather its folder was in ClearCase before but removed. I'll try to restore the folder. Thanks for the hint with the cd

Comment: @user2606240 the problem is that you need to do that for *every* parent folder of an element (was that old answer useful by the way?). It is quite cumbersome, and I prefer the cd option, taking advantage of the extended pathname of a particular element.

Comment: It's cumbersome, you're right - and cd-ing is quite elegant. I'll try to keep that in mind. And yes, the old answer was useful (marked it as the solution now, was my first post in StackOverflow and I was not too familiar with the customs here)

Comment: If you have to scan your repository and make sure you find all removed files, the following might help you: The latest version of R&D Reporter add-on for ClearCase, enables you to get a list of all removed, renamed, moved, added or changed files between the scope of two baselines or streams. This new feature is still in beta and you can download and use it. Contact beta at gomidjets dot com